# How to use the Highcharts grey theme?

Tags: highcharts

In the past I used the Highcharts grey theme to produce graphs with a dark background and light colours in the foreground. All I needed to do was to include the grey theme script:

```
<script src="http://www.highcharts.com/js/themes/gray.js"></script>
```

Including this script no longer changes the graph theme. How is it made now?

Comment: For me it still works: http://jsfiddle.net/cd6dndnd/, could you update my code with your to introduce that issue?

Comment: Working again for me too. Was the Highcharts site down somehow?

Comment: Yesterday we have some problems with URLs.